# You don't have permission to access site

Tags: wordpress

I am working on word press multisite, I have create two site via network admin, I successfully created site, but when i click on visit the child sites. i got that error,

You don't have permission to access site

Please answer me

Regards

Mubashar Ahmed

Comment: So what are the file permissions on index.php?

Comment: i just copied and pasted code in htacess and wpconfig.php file from word press network admin while configuring network. working fine on local but giving men file permission error on live

Comment: did you changed db name, username and password in config file?

Comment: Yes I have changed  in config file, actually main site is working fine, but i have created multisites , and click on visit of multisite like this  http://example.com/sitename/  ,wordpress giving me error of file You don't have permission to access 'sitename' on this server